# Total differential $\mathrm{d}h$, finding function $h(x,y)$

Tags: derivatives

I have the total differential of ${\mathrm d}h=(4x+4y){\mathrm d}x+(4x+8y){\mathrm d}y$.

How do I determine the function $h(x,y)$ that gives total differential $\mathrm{d}h$?

Comment: Are you familiar with line integrals? If so, just integrate $\mathrm dh$ over a convenient path from the origin to $(x,y)$. Just as with antiderivatives of of single-variable functions, there can also be a “constant” of integration that’s a function $f$ for which $\mathrm df=0$, so the suction is not unique.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

$$
{\rm d}h = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}{\rm d}x + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}{\rm d}y
$$

When you compare that with your original equation, you can conclude that

$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = 4x + 4y ~~~~\mbox{and}~~~~~ \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} = 4x + 8y
$$

Comment: I do understand that... It is just that when I try to think of a function that satisfies that differentiated both with respect to x and y, I go blank?

Comment: It's just like finding the potential function of a conservative vector field. Integrate with respect to one of them first, say x (which gives a $C(y)$), then differentiate wrt y and find $C(y)$. Then you've constructed $h(x,y)$

Comment: @Meowcat Follow Skip's idea: integrate the first equation w.r.t to $x$ (The integration constant is *possibly* a function of $y$) and then take the derivative w.r.t $y$ and make it equal to the second equation.